# Set Default date to be "all-date" to datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have a date picker in my rails app to choose the data from specific date but I want to set that date picker default to "All Date" to show all the data. How would I do that ?

The following code is my date picker code.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"> <!-- DATE PICKER -->
        <%= text_field_tag :date, @date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), data: {provide: 'datepicker'}, placeholder: I18n.t('admin.users.index.typing_searching_date'), class: 'form-control datepicker js-datepicker' %>
      </div>
```

Here's function to query by the date. What I currently understand is I just need to edit in that function. But I don't know how to do.

```
 @comments = @comments.where('created_at >=? AND created_at <= ?', @date.beginning_of_day, @date.end_of_day)


def get_date
    if params[:date].present?
      date = Date.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y")
      @date = date.in_time_zone
    else
      @date = DateTime.now.in_time_zone
    end
  end
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. We solved it like this - there is a select where you can choose `Current month`, `Previous month`, `All Time` and `Custom`. When selecting custom, then we are displaying the date picker. I think this is something that should work for you

Comment: I'm quite new to rails and I don't know where to add those. Can you please check my edited question ? @MrShemek

Comment: If I understand correctly you have something like this in your controller:
`Post.where(created_at: get_date)`, right? Can you provide code where you use `get_date` method?

Comment: @P.Boro , Yes ... I edited my question so that you can see now

Comment: Just add `if params[:date].present?` after the line with `@comments.where`. If you want to show all dates then you don't want to filter by date then you should not do it :P

Comment: @P.Boro Thanks It's works and I will post the answer for others users

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i fix this issue.

In View ,

```
<% if @date.present? %>
          <%= text_field_tag :date, @date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), data: {provide: 'datepicker'}, placeholder: I18n.t('admin.users.index.typing_searching_date'), class: 'form-control datepicker js-datepicker' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= text_field_tag :date, '(Any Date)',data: {provide: 'datepicker'}, placeholder: I18n.t('admin.users.index.typing_searching_date'), class: 'form-control datepicker js-datepicker' %>
        <% end %>
```

In Controller,

```
if @date.present?
    @comments = @comments.where('created_at >=? AND created_at <= ?', @date.beginning_of_day, @date.end_of_day)
    end

 if params[:date].present?
      date = Date.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y")
      @date = date.in_time_zone
end
```